# Angular 4 and PHP email sending

Tags: php, angular, email

I'a trying to send email from php send function, it is sending an email, but not populate this with any data, it is null

my code 
This is Send Service in Angular. Here my message have all data, from my form

```
    export interface IMessage {
  name?: string,
  telephon?: string,
  message?: string
}

@Injectable()
export class AppService {
  private emailUrl = '../assets/contact.php';

  constructor(private http: Http) {

  }

  sendEmail(message: IMessage): Observable<IMessage> | any {
    JSON.stringify(message);   // also tried without it
    return this.http.post(this.emailUrl, message)
      .map(response => {
        console.log('Sending email was successfull', response);
        return response;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('Sending email got error', error);
        return Observable.throw(error)
      })
  }
}
```

PHP code

```
    <?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $errors = '';
    if(empty($errors))
    {
        $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input"); // here I have null
        $request = json_decode($postdata);  // here I have null checked in console
        $from_email = $request->email;
        $message = $request->message;
        $from_name = $request->name;
        $to_email = 'myEmail@gmail.com';

        $contact = "<p><strong>Name:</strong> $from_name</p>
                                <p><strong>Email:</strong> $from_email</p>";
        $content = "<p>$message</p>";
        $website = 'My Wicked Awesome Website';
        $email_subject = "$website: Received a message from $from_name ";

        $email_body = '<html><body>';
        $email_body .= "$contact $content";
        $email_body .= '</body></html>';

        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: $from_email\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: $from_email";

        mail($to_email,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
        $response_array['status'] = 'success';
        $response_array['from'] = $from_email;
        $response_array['MESSAGE'] = $message;
        $response_array['POSTDATA'] = $postdata;
        $response_array['REQUEEST'] = $request;
        e

cho json_encode($response_array);
    echo json_encode($from_email);
    header($response_array);
    return $from_email;
} else {
    $response_array['status'] = 'error';
    echo json_encode($response_array);
    header('Location: /error.html');
}
?>
```

So what ideas?
Thanks

Comment: I found a problem, everything work nice
A problem was sendEmail service got empty message

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to define variables:

```
// JS - remove JSON.stringify
sendEmail(message: IMessage): Observable<IMessage> | any {
    return this.http.post(this.emailUrl, message)
    ...

// PHP
$message = filter_input('message', '', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$from_name = filter_input('name', '', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Answer (score 0):

you just going to get the post data in php

change

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

to

```
$message = $_POST['message'];
```

Comment: But  http.post method need to get 2 parametrs, here you send 1 object and it doesn`t work

Comment: This: this.http.post(data) , code does not compile
I know that data it is object that contains email and message, but post() see only 1 parametr

Comment: leave the service code as it is and add header to it just change the php code

Comment: Also not
I did
`
JSON.stringify(message);
return this.http.post(this.emailUrl, {msg: message})
`
PHP
`
$msg =  $_POST['msg'];
`
It still Null

Comment: try with JSON.stringify({msg: message})

Comment: Nope
Also trying option from second answer here. It is won`t work
From Console:
e {_body: "{"status":"success","from":null,"MESSAGE":null,"POSTDATA":null,"REQUEEST":null}null", status: 200, ok: true, statusText: "OK", headers: t…}

Comment: where are you calling the service  sendEmail can you show that code too

Comment: `code sendEmail(message: IMessage) {
    this.appService.sendEmail(message).subscribe(res => {
      console.log('AppComponent Success', res);
    }, error => {
      console.log('AppComponent Error', error);
    });
    console.log(message)
  }`